# Run PHP SQL query command when link clicked on

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I want there to be a SQL query to take place when a link is clicked on, so far this is what I have:

mainpage.php:

```
function deleteImage1() {
    $.post("delete_image.php", { num:1, id:<?php echo $id; ?> }, function(data,status){
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
    return false;
}

<a href="#" onclick="deleteImage1()">Delete Image</a>
```

delete_image.php:

```
<?php

// $connect stuff here 

    $num = $_GET['num'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if ($num === '1') {
    $image_num == '';
    } else {
    $image_num == $num;
    }

    $sqlCommand = mysql_query("UPDATE alpacas1 SET image$image_num='' WHERE id=$id");

if (!$sqlCommand) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
 echo "Updated successfully!";
}
?>
```

Now, when I click on the "Delete Image" link, it try's to run the function, and it does, but returns as this in the popup:

> Data: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds with your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near " at line 1. 
>   Status: success

But when I reload the page, (or look in the database), the image field has not been changed to '' (or null).

Also, I have tested the SQL query so it is not that. I have done so by visiting delete_image.php in my browser with the id & num variables being "posted" (ex. delete_image.php?num=1&id=20) and by visiting it IN BROWSER, it SUCCESSFULLY deletes the image and gives me the message "Updated successfully!".

I'm guessing it's something with my Javascript as I am a beginner! Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the code in _mainpage.php_ that declares `$id`?

Comment: Sorry, the page is huge, didn't include that, but it is a PHP GET function that get's it, and it works, because I use it for many other functions on the page.

Comment: Here is the function when I "inspect element" on Google Chrome. As you can see, the $id variable displays correctly when asked.
`function deleteImage1() {
    $.post("delete_image.php", { num:1, id:286 }, function(data,status){
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
    return false;
}`

Comment: This code looks extremely vulnerable to SQL injection if used in a live site. I **strongly** recommend using either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) with a parameterized query.

Comment: It's the backend which is password protected, one user going to be using it, so SQL injection isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should've noticed this earlier...

You're using the jQuery `.post()`, yet you're accessing the variables as if they are sent via `GET`. You should either use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` to pull in your data:

```
$num = $_POST['num'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Without the proper variables, your query reads:

`UPDATE alpacas1 SET image='' WHERE id="`

Thus the MySQL error is returned.

Comment: Ah I should have caught that also!! Thanks man, just what I needed, I've tried so many things I'm lost in my own code.

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes to catch the simple mistakes.